# Filling the database with values from Index with ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Trying to fill the database with test data.

- When I click the button to insert the data: 
  I get this in the consol: XHR finished loading: POST "htp://localhost:50957/".

And nothing happens, could anybody help?

Index.cshtml:

```
<input type="submit" class=" btn" value="FilldataBase" id="fill" data-loading-text="Loading..." />

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#fill').click(function () {
                    var url = "/FaqController/Filler">
                    $.post(url);

                });
            });
        </script>
```

In the Controller:

```
 public void Filler()
        {
            var filler = new DBFiller();
            filler.Filler();
        }
```

DBFiller.cs is located in the same level as Web.config file.

DBFiller.cs

```
public class DBFiller
{
    public void Filler()
    {
         using (var entity = new FaqModel())
        {

            entity.SubmittedQuestions.Add(new SubmittedQuestion()
            {
                Name = "someinfor.",
                CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Today,
                UserEmail = "some@info.com",
                QuestionText = "info.",
                Category = new Category()
                {
                    Name = "Data"

                },
            });
```

}}}

Comment: What Im missing, I have updated my Post With DBfiller.cshtml.
- actually this works on another project which was an mvc project.

Now Im trying to use the same code with an angularjs project.

Comment: In the console it tells you `XHR finished loading: POST "htp://localhost:50957/` instead of `XHR finished loading: POST "htp://localhost:50957/FaqController/Filler` so that means it is not POSTing to `/FaqController/Filler`... Interesting...

Comment: At the end of this line `var url = "/FaqController/Filler"` why is there a `>`? Try removing it...

Comment: @Ignaus after removing ">" I get this in the consol:

POST http://localhost:50957/FaqController/Filler 404 (Not Found) 
---
<html ng-app="FaqAngularJSApp" ng-controller="LandingPageController">

In my index.cshtml I use angular controller do I need any POST METHOD  in the LandingPageController?

Comment: Hm... @wodwin Try making a new page with just an HTML form on it who's method is `POST` and action is `localhost:50957/FaqController/Filler` and see if the data gets inserted into the DB, because this could just be jQuery/AJAX being weird...

Comment: But as for any AngularJs-related error messages, I can't be of assistance because I have no experience with AngularJs.

Comment: Try decorating `Filler` method with `[HttpPost]` attribute.